# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 in recursive sorting

Tags: java, sorting

Am new in Java, I want to know why i have exceptions even though i got the answers i  required. Below is the Source code

```
package habeeb;

import java.util.*;

public class Habeeb
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[30];
        int i, count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100");
        for (i = 1; i <= num.length; i++)
        {
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (num[i] == 0)
                break;
            count++;
        }
        Sorting(num, i, count);
    }

    public static void Sorting(int[] sort, int a, int con)
    {
        int j, count = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= con; j++)
        {
            if (sort[a] == sort[j])
                count++;
        }
        System.out.println(sort[a] + " occurs " + count + " times");
        Sorting(sort, a - 1, con);
    }
}
```

And here is the output

> ```
> run:
> Enter the integers between 1 and 100
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 2
> 2
> 4
> 5
> 3
> 6
> 1
> 0
> 0 occurs 0 times
> 1 occurs 2 times
> 6 occurs 1 times
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
> 3 occurs 2 times
> 5 occurs 1 times
> 4 occurs 1 times
> 2 occurs 3 times
> 2 occurs 3 times
> 3 occurs 2 times
> 2 occurs 3 times
> 1 occurs 2 times
> 0 occurs 0 times
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:18)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting(Habeeb.java:21)
>  at habeeb.Habeeb.main(Habeeb.java:14)
>  Java Result: 1
> ```

Comment: I added formatting to your post, but the indentation is still messed up - making it hard to read.  The error is that you are referring to sort[-1] somewhere in the code.  Have you tried printing out the value of the index to see where this is occuring?

Comment: Well, you used an array index of -1 in habeeb.Habeeb.Sorting at line 18.

Comment: Probably because you executed this line when a was == 0: `Sorting(sort, a-1, con);`

Comment: Fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Sorting(int[] sort, int a, int con){
int j, count=0;
for(j=1; j<=con; j++){
  if(sort[a]==sort[j])
   count++;
}System.out.println(sort[a]+" occurs "+count+" times"); 
Sorting(sort, a-1, con);
```

Should be:

```
public static void Sorting(int[] sort, int a, int con){
if(a<0)return;
int j, count=0;
for(j=1; j<=con; j++){
  if(sort[a]==sort[j])
   count++;
}System.out.println(sort[a]+" occurs "+count+" times"); 
Sorting(sort, a-1, con);
```

Comment: Better if you give some explanation, rather than just post a code

Comment: Ok buddy. at some point a will = 0. Now when the next recursive call is made it will pass >> Sorting(sort, 0-1, con);... then when sort[a] is evaluated - it will be trying to get the array element at '-1' :)

Comment: So, if(a<0)return; is the "terminator condition"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 1; i <= num.length; i++){
    num[i] = input.nextInt();

    if (num[i] == 0)
        break;

    count++;
}
```

**i** in your loop takes values between **1** - **num.length** where **num.length** = 30.

So at some point, your program tries to execute

```
num[30] = input.nextInt();
```

which will result in an error! Cos **30** out of the bound of the array indices. The correct range of index should be between **0** and **29**.

Two possible corrections are:

Loop from 0 - (num.length - 1):

```
for(i = 0; i <= num.length - 1; i++){

    num[i] = input.nextInt();

    if (num[i] == 0)
        break;

    count++;
}
```

Loop from 1 - num.length as before, but update the index of **num** appropriately:

```
for(i = 1; i <= num.length1; i++){

    int index = i - 1;

    num[index] = input.nextInt();

    if (num[index] == 0)
        break;

    count++;
}
```